Prevent same getter being called twice with chained getters
I am building a painter that can chain getters, but each getter can only be called once. For TextDecorator and BgDecorator, they are easy to handle because I can just return different classes. However, for StyleDecorator, since it is allowed to apply multiple styles, I don't know how to define a type that can accumulate omitted getters. Please see the code below:
class Painter {
  protected textColor: string
  protected bgColor: string
  protected styles: string[]

  paint() {
    // paint the text
  }
  static create() {
    return new TextDecorator()
  }
}

class StyleDecorator extends Painter  {
  get bold(): Omit<StyleDecorator, 'bold'> {
    this.styles.push('bold')
    return this
  }
  get underline(): Omit<StyleDecorator, 'underline'> {
    this.styles.push('underline')
    return this
  }
  get italic(): Omit<StyleDecorator, 'italic'> {
    this.styles.push('italics')
    return this
  }
}

class BgDecorator extends StyleDecorator {
  get redBg(): StyleDecorator {
    this.bgColor = "red"
    return this
  }
  get blueBg(): StyleDecorator {
    this.bgColor = "blue"
    return this
  }
}

class TextDecorator extends BgDecorator {
  get white(): BgDecorator {
    this.textColor = "white"
    return this
  }
  get black(): BgDecorator {
    this.textColor = "black"
    return this
  }

}



Painter.create().white.redBg.bold.underline.paint() // ok
Painter.create().white.blueBg.bold.underline.bold.paint() // I want to see error that says bold does not exist.
Painter.create().white.redBg.underline.bold.underline.paint() // I want to see error that says underline does not exist.
Painter.create().white.redBg.italic.underline.italic.underline.paint() // I want to see error that says underline and italic do not exist.

I looked at this by lukasgeiter and this by Titain they are close to what I want to achieve, but they are not getters.

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Just if (this.styles.includes("bold")) throw new Error()? Or are you looking for compile-time type errors?

I think you can directly apply the approach from this answer you found. Whether they are getters, or getter methods, shouldn't make much a difference.

@jcalz Yes that is exactly what I want, please add this to the answer I will accept it. If you can add some explanation that would be good. Thank you!

I'll do so when I get a chance.

What's happening with the edits here? Any reason why we're changing italics to italic while still using "italics" in styles? Surely this doesn't have anything to do with the  example, does it?  It's forcing me to edit my in-progress answer to keep up and I'm not sure what the point is.

As an alternative you can avoid using child classes for type validation and just use a generic Proxy for all your colors and styles, moreover you can type your Painter properties instead of using string.
This also allows you to type styles and colors in any order (for good or for bad).
For good is that you can define default colors (for example white bg and black text) and set only text styles. I think it's more flexible than using child classes where you HAVE to set the color to set the background. Seems like a non pleasant limitation.
Typescript Playground
const colors = ['white', 'black', 'red', 'blue'] as const;
const styles = ['underline', 'bold', 'italic'] as const;

type Color = typeof colors[number];
type BgColor = keyof { [K in Color as `${K}Bg`]: never };
type Style = typeof styles[number];

// sets for faster lookups
const colorSet = new Set(colors);
const bgColorSet = new Set(colors.map(c => `${c}Bg`) as BgColor[]);
const styleSet = new Set(styles);

type AllStyles = Color | BgColor | Style;

type Decorator<T extends AllStyles = never> = Omit<{
    [K in Style]: Omit<Decorator<T | K>, K>
}, T> & Omit<{
    [K in Color]: Omit<Decorator<T | Color>, Color>
}, T> & Omit<{
    [K in BgColor]: Omit<Decorator<T | BgColor>, BgColor>
}, T> & 
Painter;

class Painter {
    protected textColor: Color | '' = ""
    protected bgColor: Color | '' = ""
    protected styles: Style[] = []

    paint() {
        console.log(this);
    }
    static create(): Decorator { 
        return new Proxy<Decorator>(new Painter as Decorator, {
            get(target, prop, proxy){               
                if(colorSet.has(prop as Color)){
                    target.textColor = prop as Color;
                }else if(bgColorSet.has(prop as BgColor)){
                    target.bgColor = prop as Color;
                }else if(styleSet.has(prop as Style)){
                    target.styles.push(prop as Style);
                }else {
                    return Reflect.get(target, prop, proxy);
                }
                return proxy;
            }
        });

    }
}

Painter.create().white.black.redBg.bold.underline.paint() // black is an error
Painter.create().white.blueBg.bold.underline.bold.paint() // I want to see error that says bold cannot be called twice.
Painter.create().white.redBg.underline.bold.underline.paint() // I want to see error that says underline cannot be called twice.
Painter.create().white.redBg.italic.underline.italic.underline.paint() // I want to see error that says underline and italics cannot be called twice.


Hey @Alex I found your solution is actually what I was looking for at the beginning. Because I didn't know how to do that so I came up sub classes solutions. But yours is  more elegant. But I already accept Jcalz's answer and it is more relevant to this question. Do you want me to create another questions and you can copy the answer there?

I created one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78560317/how-to-dynamically-add-getters-to-a-class-based-on-enum-values-also-prevent-the

@Arst lol it's closed

Oh hey @Arst you unaccepted my answer despite the fact that I checked with you about whether the typings of your code were what you were looking for. This refactoring might be better for your underlying use case, but isn't what you asked for. It's your prerogative to decide another answer is better and to unaccept mine, but... is there anything I should have done differently to avoid this situation?

@jcalz don't take it hard, i was unaccepted many times and didn't draw any complaints about. in the end the goal is to find the best solution despite the original question. as my apology receive my vote please, thanks

@Arst it was a deep night when i posted my answer and i didn't manage to copy the latest version from the playground. I've updated my answer and remove the constructor proxy since you use a static factory method to create a painter and you don't need to support new keyword

@AlexanderNenashev you don't need to apologize and Arst doesn't need to either, but thank you for your response.

You need StyleDecorator to keep track of which properties have already been omitted. Otherwise you'll end up just forgetting everything except the most recent operation. That would prevent painter.bold.bold but it wouldn't do anything to stop painter.bold.underline.bold.
You want the bold property of a StyleDecorator to be of type Omit<StyleDecorator, "bold" | K> where K is whatever you've already omitted. That means StyleDecorator should be generic in K, meaning that every time you Omit you have to also have to add the currently called method name to K via union.
That looks like:
type StyleDecoratorWithout<K extends PropertyKey> = Omit<StyleDecorator<K>, K>;

class StyleDecorator<K extends PropertyKey = never> extends Painter {
    get bold() {
        this.styles.push('bold')
        return this as StyleDecoratorWithout<K | "bold">
    }
    get underline() {
        this.styles.push('underline')
        return this as StyleDecoratorWithout<K | "underline">
    }
    get italic() {
        this.styles.push('italic')
        return this as StyleDecoratorWithout<K | "italic">
    }
}

Painter.create().white.redBg.bold.underline.paint() // ok
Painter.create().white.blueBg.bold.underline.bold.paint() // error
Painter.create().white.redBg.underline.bold.underline.paint() // error
Painter.create().white.redBg.italic.underline.italic.underline.paint() // error

So Painter.create().white is of type StyleDecorator<never>. The bold property of that is StyleDecoratorWithour<"bold">, meaning it has no "bold" property (since we Omitted "bold") and that any of its other properties will include "bold" in the list of things to omit.  Then the underline property of that is StyleDecoratorWithout<"bold" | "underline">, so it has no "bold" nor "underline" property.  After this you can access the italic property, which is StyleDecoratorWithout<"bold" | "underline" | "italic"> which has none of those three properties.  You're effectively prohibited from easily accessing the same property multiple times in a chained getter.

That's the answer to the question as asked.
But note this doesn't actually stop you from accessing the same property multiple times without chaining:
const p = Painter.create().white
p.bold;
p.bold;
console.log(p["styles"]) // ["bold", "bold"], oops

And if you need to prevent that then you'll find it essentially impossible in TypeScript (since it would require you to keep track of arbitrary mutable state on a given variable, which TypeScript can't do.) I'd recommend you make sure the actual code can handle having the property accessed multiple times (say by not push()ing if it already exists; use a Set maybe?  But this is a digression from the question as asked.
Playground link to code
